# postgres cast "number" varchar with commas and dots into integer

Tags: sql, postgresql, casting, sum

I have a column that has a numeric value formatted as a string with commas and dots, e.g `1.000,50` or `100,00`.

I want to cast these varchars into a number, in order to `sum` them in a query. How can I do this?

```sql
SELECT sum(replace(string_num, '.','')::REAL) FROM sales; --not working, just illustrating
```

I expect a sum of all the casted integers

Comment: What results do you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that you want to get rid of the `.`s and replace the `,`s with `.` and add as numerics:

```
sum(replace(replace(string_num, '.', ''), ',', '.'))
```

Comment: Perfect! Will mark as answer when possible